# Including sysinfoapi.h or fileapi.h causes "No Target Architecture" errors?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have a project that compiles fine under MSYS/Mingw. However, it fails under Visual Studio.

If I try to include the either `sysinfoapi.h` or `fileapi.h` I get a slew of errors in Visual Studio. No such errors occur in MSYS.

[image: An image of the errors]

I do have two copies of the Windows Software Development Kit, versions 10.1.22000.194 and 10.1.17763.132 both installed. (Some forums discussing the topic mention missing SDK can cause similar issues)

Comment: `#include <Windows.h>` needs to go first.

Comment: @HansPassant That seems to have fixed it! I wonder why it worked OK in MSYS but failed in VS? If you want to turn this into an answer, I will mark it as solved.